# How are the tiles on Lynda made?

Tags: javascript, jquery, web

I understand it's some degree of JavaScript, but it's not something I know how to do despite knowing a reasonable amount of it.

Firstly, the hover-flip animations, that can't be a CSS switch, because I've never seen a transition quite like it.

Comment: OK, so I visited Lynda.com in chrome I right-clicked selected "inspect-element", and saw that "flip-container" was a css class assigned to the elements that were flipping. Then I googled "flip-container". The first hit is this post: http://davidwalsh.name/css-flip.

Comment: The above process doesn't always yield such a great result but its is certainly the first step to qualifying your effort as reasonable before posting to Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very easy to do this sort of check yourself. In this case it is CSS so simply opening the browser console and inspecting the element would tell you that there are two elements, `.front` and `.back` position on top of each other absolutely, and the animation is a `transform:rotateY(180deg)` on hover along with a `transition: all 0.6s ease 0s` to slow it down.

If there is ever a JS animation you are trying to figure out, learn how to use JS breakpoints. You can also break on DOM attribute change, which will be useful for most animations that involve some css or class changes.

To learn more visit http://davidwalsh.name/css-flip.